# Mathematica 11.3 not working over X11

Tags: wolfram-engine

I'm trying to access Mathematica 11.3 remotely over X11 using XQuartz on Mac El Captain, but to no success. The terminal script is below, chromium-browser launches ok after numerous messages bu mathematica outputs two lines, which I have seen before, and just hangs

> samwise:~ nwalton$ ssh -Y pi@wormtongue.local pi@wormtongue.local's
>
> password:
> Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for
> X11 forwarding. Linux wormtongue 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4
> 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l
>
> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free
> software; the exact distribution terms for each program are described
> in the individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
>
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by applicable law. Last login: Thu Nov 29 19:18:21 2018 from
> 192.168.1.23 pi@wormtongue:~ $ chromium-browser   --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --disable-gpu-compositing --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version= Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 160: blank doesn't
> take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
> [1638:1638:1129/193921.154668:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1029)]
> Lost UI shared context.
> [1638:1783:1129/193927.348961:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to
> the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type
> (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix") ATTENTION:
> default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error:
> failed to load driver: swrast
> [1789:1789:1129/193946.490720:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't
> make context current with X drawable.
> [1789:1789:1129/193946.491024:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(62)]
> gl::GLContext::MakeCurrent() failed pi@wormtongue:~
> $ mathematica -version
>
> 11.3
>
> pi@wormtongue:~ $ mathematica
>
> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Is the problem Mathematica, Pi or XQuartz?

Comment: During your ssh session, what is the output of `echo -e "Display = $DISPLAY\n" && xauth list`  ... and also `glxinfo`

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error using ssh -Y, but it works fine if I use ssh -X
I don't know why it creates that error, but if you don't need a trusted forwarding to avoid the X11 security extension that ssh -X has on by default then try ssh -X.

Read the ssh man page if my explanation of the two options doesn't make sense